# Relationship between two nodes not being formed in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

When I create two nodes and then make a relation between them as:

```
CREATE(cc:CreditCard{id:"5001",number:"1234567890",cvv:"888",expiry:"02/17"})
```

then

```
CREATE (e:Customer{id:"1001",name:"Abc",dob:"01/10/1982"})
```

and then

```
MATCH (e:Customer),(cc:CreditCard) CREATE(e)-[r:Shop]->(cc)
```

the following error comes:

> This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.
>    If a part of a query contains multiple disconnected patterns, this
>   will build a cartesian 
>    product between all those parts.
>    This may produce a large amount of data and slow down query
>   processing.
>
> While occasionally intended, it may often be possible to reformulate
>   the query that avoids 
>    the use of this cross product, perhaps by adding a relationship
>   between the different parts
>    or by using OPTIONAL MATCH

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. You are linking every `Customer` to every `CreditCard`, not linking only the two nodes you just created.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have a single customer node and two creditcard nodes with each card having a different expiry date. How can I create a relation between my customer node and one of the CreditCard nodes?

Comment: By *being specific*, e.g. `MATCH (e:Customer { id: "1001" }), ...` or using a `WHERE c.id = "1001"`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am using this query and still getting the same warning    `match (e:Customer{id:"1001"}),(cc:CreditCard {expiry:"02/17"}) create(e)-[r:DoShop]->(cc)`

Comment: **Again**, it's just a *warning*. You're still doing a query that *could* be a Cartesian product because those attributes aren't constrained. Also more than one credit card can have the same expiry date.